# Gulp - strip out test code then webpack modules

Tags: webpack, gulp

I'm new to gulp and am trying to understand how to set up a gulp recipe to strip out test test code with 'gulp-strip-code' and 'webpack-stream'.

For testing purposes I'm not doing any minification on the file.

```
gulp.task('strip-test-code', function(){
  return gulp.src(['src/*.js','src/gui/*.js'],{base:'src'})
    .pipe(stripCode({
      start_comment: "start-test-block",
      end_comment: "end-test-block"
    }));
});

gulp.task('pack-strip',['strip-test-code'],function(){
  return gulp.src(['src/*.js','src/gui/*.js'],{base:'src'})
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.devel.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

When I run `gulp pack-strip` I still see my test bock tags in the bundle.

It seems to be running the strip-test-code.

```
[10:26:57] Using gulpfile ~/project/gulpfile.js
[10:26:57] Starting 'strip-test-code'...
[10:26:57] Finished 'strip-test-code' after 71 ms
[10:26:57] Starting 'pack-strip'...
[10:26:58] Version: webpack 1.15.0
              Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
project.bundle.js  141 kB       0  [emitted]  project
[10:26:58] Finished 'pack-strip' after 396 ms
```

However after execution i grep for the test block

```
grep -r start-test-block *
dist/project.bundle.js:   /*start-test-block*/
```

--- EDIT ---

My webpack config file looks like

```
 1 const path=require('path');
 2 module.exports={
 3   context:path.resolve(__dirname,'src'),
 4   entry:{
 5     project:['./project.js']
 6   },
 7   output:{
 8     path:path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
 9     filename:'[name].bundle.js'
10   },
11   devtool:"#inline-source-map"
12 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task `pack-strip` didn't use the stream return by task `strip-test-code`, you could combine them into one task:

```
gulp.task('task', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/*.js','src/gui/*.js'],{base:'src'})
       .pipe(stripCode({
           start_comment: "start-test-block",
           end_comment: "end-test-block"
       }))
       .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.devel.js')))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Or you could save the stripped files firstly and read them later:

```
gulp.task('strip-test-code', function(){
     return gulp.src(['src/*.js','src/gui/*.js'],{base:'src'})
         .pipe(stripCode({
             start_comment: "start-test-block",
             end_comment: "end-test-block"
          }));
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('pack-strip',['strip-test-code'],function(){
    return gulp.src(['dist/*.js','dist/gui/*.js'],{base:'dist'})
        .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.devel.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: I would prefer to do option one but it doesn't seem to work.  Could it be because of the webpack.config.devel.js script picking up the originals?

Comment: Right, if you are using webpack with gulp, you don't need to define the `entry` in webpack config file

Comment: Removing the entry point changed the bundle name.  And doesn't seem to allow for multiple entry points.

Comment: While I would have preferred option 1.  I ultimately wen with option 2.  This allowed me to specify multiple entry points for my webpack.  Also I scrapped with webpack config file altogether and in-lined it in my gulp recipe.